# How to optimize when you repeat a select multiple times in another select?

Tags: mysql, select, optimization

I'm calculating business hours between two dates from a big database and it's working.
However the request is very long because of a lot of select.
I'm trying to optimize it but it seems I can't use alias.
Any ideas ?

Here's a view of my problem :

I have a first date: SELECT A :

```
 SELECT CASE
 WHEN (... = 9) 
 THEN ( SELECT ... )
        ELSE  (SELECT ... FROM ...
        WHERE ( (...) AND (...) AND 
        ( (...='1' OR ...'10009' OR ...='10011') AND ...='3') )
        )
    END 
  FROM ...
```

and my second date: SELECT B  :

```
    SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN (...) AND ...
        THEN(   SELECT ... FROM ...
              WHERE  ( (... 
              AND (...) AND (...) 
              AND (... ) )  )   
        WHEN (...) AND ...
        THEN(   SELECT ... FROM ...
                 WHERE ( ... ) AND ... AND ... AND ... AND ... )
        ELSE NULL
    END 
)
```

Then I copy them in the following query (which is inside another big query... for a report with multiple columns) :

```
SELECT (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, GetBusinessHours(SELECT A),GetBusinessHours(SELECT B)) 
- 13*60*DATEDIFF( GetBusinessHours(SELECT B) , GetBusinessHours(SELECT A) )
- 2*11*60*(WEEK(SELECT B) - WEEK(SELECT A) )
- SELECT COUNT(*) FROM X WHERE DATE BETWEEN ((SELECT A) AND (SELECT B))
```

So this last query becomes huge and it takes 70 lines. Is there a way to optimize the fact that I don't have to recalculate 4 times each SELECT A and SELECT B ?

Comment: Use `explain` to exactly pinpoint where it's slow. Don't calculate the result all the time, cache it (or materialize it). What you're left with is creating an event that will pre-calculate this for you based on intervals so your app is left with reading the data (which will always be quick). Until the explain output arrives, we can just speculate what's exactly slow. Since it's a big database in question, I suspect there's some heavy disk seeking involved as well which we avoid by allocating RAM for such purposes.

Comment: Thanks.
I checked Explain and saw 100000+ rows 10 times. It's in a dependent subquery in one of my SELECT A or B but the lines differs a lot from the others.
The type is index, possible_keys are null, ref is null and say in Extra : using index. 
I will check where it is exactly and try to extract if from all the script.

Comment: Well, it's doing a full table scan. Posting the table structure, exact output of explain and exact query would help, but it seems you're calculating business hours by using the entire contents of the table. That involves disk seeks and since you probably have a mechanical drive (and not an SSD) - it takes a while to find the data. I doubt you can optimize this easily without caching results and using the cache in future queries..

Comment: Some of the base is kinda private so I can't post it without anonymising it and it will take some time to do it.
Your last sentence is a way to go and a really good answer I can give for my boss in a first approach. I was thinking to use another table to store some datas but I can't do it because we can't create another table (very strict dba)... and yes, I forgot that but the server is old so disk seeks can take a lot of time.

Comment: I understand your situation completely. I can also relate to your DBA but materializing results of queries is an old technique and I believe you should approach your boss and the DBA in a way so that they can see the proper gain of creating another table which would be used for this report.. it's really the least amount of work for all of you for maximum possible gain. No reason to induce technological debt upon yourselves for no reason :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plan A:  Create temp tables with the common data.

Plan B:  Use @variables.  For example:

```
SELECT @A := expression1...;
SELECT @B := expression2...;
SELECT ... @A ... @B ... @A ...
```